# How do I get VMware vCenter Converter image back on an empty machine?

Tags: vmware, clone

If I use VMware vCenter Converter to make a clone of a machine, and I have another machine with nothing on it, nothing on the hard drive.  How can I get that clone on the new machine?  What do I do?  I've looked at VMWare's page but I don't understand.

I am trying to do something like Clonezilla but not using Clonezilla.

The OS I want to clone and restore is Windows 7 Pro.

Comment: I don't believe VMware vCenter Converter supports restoring a virtual hdd to a physical hdd.

Comment: I should clarify my statement. This tool is design to convert a physical machine to a VMWare virtual machine or migrate some other virtual machine image form to the VMWare image format. This tool itself does not have capability to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The vCenter Converter is for cloning VMs . . . meaning from one server running vmware to another server running vmware.

It sounds like you're trying to use it as a backup tool to make an image of a running machine (physical? VM?) and clone it to a physical machine.  The Converter won't do this and you'll need to use system imaging tools, not VM tools.

Comment: You came to the same conclusion I did.  Now of course VCenter Server, ESX and ESXi servers could also be used.  The converter tool doesn't do what the author needs.

Comment: Thanks.  I was trying to get some way to clone machines without having to bring them down like you do with Clonezilla.  I have seen a few other products but they did not work so well.